# How do I make the MUI Dialog title an H1 element so the modal is accessible

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, accessibility

I'm working on making my app more accessible and am struggling with the MUI Dialog component. I'm using the DialogTitle component, which creates an H2 element and am getting an issue of "page doesn't contain a level-one heading". Should I be creating my modal in some other way, or are MUI Dialogs just not accessible?

```
import { Dialog, DialogTitle } from '@mui/material';

const MyModal = () => {

    return (
        <Dialog open={true}>
            <DialogTitle>
                My Title
            </DialogTitle>
        </Dialog>
    );
};

export default MyModal;
```

Comment: @steve's solution sounds good but if it doesn't work, don't worry about the dialog heading being an `<h2>` instead of an `<h1>`.  As long as it's the "smallest" heading level in your dialog (if you happen to have other headings in the dialog), then you're ok from an accessibility perspective.  There's nothing that says you **must** have an `<h1>`.  Whatever scanning tool you're using that generates that "error" is purely subjective on the scanning tool coder's opinion.  There is **nothing** in WCAG that says you must have an `<h1>`.

Answer (score 9):

**Updated for MUI v5:**

The [`Dialog`](https://mui.com/api/dialog/) component API includes a helper [`DialogTitle`](https://mui.com/api/dialog-title/) component which, by default, renders its contents within an `h2` element.  To change this functionality, you can pass the `component` property to the `DialogTitle` to have the `DialogTitle` rendered using whatever `elementType` that you wish.  For example:

```
<DialogTitle component="h1">
  My Dialog Title
</DialogTitle>
```

*This is currently an undocumented feature of `DialogTitle`, but it can been seen in the [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/5daaf9be5115b1cb777fb4cf3d9125baddfe5720/packages/mui-material/src/DialogTitle/DialogTitle.js#L50) that properties that are passed to `DialogTitle` are spread onto the underlying `Typography` component -- By passing `component`, you are essentially overwriting the hardcoded `component="h2"` prop with your own value.*

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/simpledialog-material-demo-forked-kpq9k?file=/demo.js

**Original answer for MUI v4:**

The [`Dialog`](https://v4.mui.com/api/dialog/) component API includes a helper [`DialogTitle`](https://v4.mui.com/api/dialog-title/) component which, by default, renders its contents within an `h2` element.  To disable this functionality, you can use the `DialogTitle` component with the `disableTypography` prop (to disable the `h2` wrapping behavior) and then include your own [`Typography`](https://v4.mui.com/api/typography/) component set to `h1`. For example:

```
<DialogTitle disableTypography>
  <Typography variant="h1">My Dialog Title</Typography>
</DialogTitle>
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-7pso2?file=/demo.js

Extra Credit: You may then come across the problem that the `h1` is styled "too large" for your design. If so, and you prefer the `h2` look, you can use the `Typography` prop named `component` in combination with the `variant` prop to visually style it back to an `h2`, while maintaining the underlying `h1` element.  For example:

```
<DialogTitle disableTypography>
  <Typography variant="h2" component="h1">My Dialog Title</Typography>
</DialogTitle>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I should have mentioned that I'm using the newer version of MUI (v5) and the disableTypography prop no longer exists. https://mui.com/api/dialog-title/ I've tried including a typography element as the child of the DialogTitle, but it just places the H1 inside the H2 which obviously doesn't work either

Comment: I updated my question to include a version of my code -- sorry for not doing that originally, first time asking a question here!!

Comment: @LailaZoghi The answer has been updated for MUI 5 as well.

Comment: The component prop doesn't work in typescript which I should have mentioned I'm using in the question (sorry again)...any ideas for typescript?

Comment: The typescript definitions don't include this property, and they match the documentation for v5 DialogTitle, which doesn't mention it either: https://mui.com/api/dialog-title/ .  Is this a MUI bug?

Comment: Indeed, with TS it throws an error when trying to add a `component` prop. Nevermind, if you prepend with `@ts-expect-error` to let it build the app, it works :) However, that's still a **dirty workaround**

Comment: The **better workaround** (and **the cleanest**) I see, **would be playing with CSS** (in a styled component for eg)

Answer (score 5):

In the case of TypeScript there's no typing provided so you need to do a hack:

```js
<DialogTitle {...{ component: 'div' } as any}>
  <Typography variant="h1">My Dialog Title</Typography>
</DialogTitle>
```

This is a temporary hack until they add the typing for all the props there.

Answer (score 0):

As @Steve mentionned, in Mui v5, the job is harder. Even if you specify a `component` prop (which won't work in TS, moreover it's a bad practice), it won't change the style as it renders a h2 with a h6-style.

The cleanest workaround would be to mess with CSS (in a styled component for eg)

```js
// Styling
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

// UI
import { DialogTitle as MuiDialogTitle } from "@mui/material";


const DialogTitle = styled(MuiDialogTitle)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&.MuiDialogTitle-root.MuiTypography-root": {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
}));
```